# Help with a spreadsheet calculation

Tags: trigonometry

I thought this would be a simple excel spreadsheet... I want to have a calculator for installing crown molding at different angles.

Wikipedia posted the formula ([formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_molding))

The answers never work out.  Pictured is what I wrote.  And I also tried hard-coding a test at the bottom.

I should be getting 31.62 and 33.86 respectively.

Am I using the wrong formula?

[image]

Comment: You have to turn 90 and 38 into radians before you start applying the sin/cos/tan s

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel uses radians rather than degrees.  So, the formulas would be

Miter Cut

=+DEGREES(ATAN(SIN(RADIANS(B3)/TAN(RADIANS(B1)/2))))

Bevel Cut

=+DEGREES(ASIN(COS(RADIANS(B3))*COS(RADIANS(B1)/2)))

Comment: Wow, thank you.  Learn something new every day